# Does temperature affect the index of refraction?

Tags: temperature, material-science, refraction, home-experiment, optical-materials

I would like to know the physical reasoning behind the fact that temperature indeed does change the index of refraction of a certain medium.

(Is there an easy experiment for me to try this at home?)

Answer (score 3):

Refractive index does not change because of a change in temperature, it changes because of a change in density. Increased temperature usually reduces density because most materials expand when heated (but some contract). If density is kept the same while temperature changes (eg by varying applied pressure) then there is no change in refractive index.

A simple Science Fair experiment which you could do at home/school is described in the following reports :
http://cssf.usc.edu/History/2008/Projects/J1625.pdf
http://cssf.usc.edu/History/2006/Projects/S1513.pdf
However, these experiments do not make any compensation for the change in density, so it is impossible to tell if the results obtained are due to change in temperature or change in density.

It is difficult to eliminate or compensate for changes in density during the experiment. You could compensate after the experiment by obtaining and plotting data for density of the material at various temperatures within the experimental range and comparing with your measured variation in refractive index. If the two values remain in proportion as temperature varies then you can deduce that the variation is entirely due to density and not at all due to temperature.

Comment: Thank you, the experiments that you have linked me show change in temperature of a liquid (e.g. water). Let us say I want to see what happens if we change the temperature of surrounding air when performing Young's double slit experiment, would it be ok to heat room to 30 degrees celsius and compare it to the first experiment originally at 16 degreees celsius (using air conditioner)?

Comment: Your suggestion would not compensate for change of density of the air, which remains at atmospheric pressure and therefore expands, decreasing its density. You would have to seal the room (or apparatus) air-tight to ensure that air density does not change.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Is that experimentally feasible at home? Do you suggest anyway that I can do this experiment?

Comment: The index of refraction at constant density is only (approximately) independent of temperature as long you have no appreciable ionization of the optical medium. At high temperatures air becomes a plasma wit a significantly different index of refraction.

Comment: @uioghhenft No I do not think it is feasible to prevent air from expanding in an "easy" home experiment. You would have to be in a school or university laboratory to do this. ... However, do you really need to keep the density constant? For most practical purposes, it does not make any difference whether the change is due to density or not. It is assumed that pressure is constant, not density. So provided that you keep the (atmospheric) pressure constant, your results will be ok.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, so I can practically see a change in interference pattern if I changed the room temperature using an air conditioner?

Answer (score 1):

The change of density with temperature is not the only source of temperature dependence of refractive indices. Another cause is the change of polarizability with temperature (at constant density) (see [equation 35 in the *Handbook of Optics* (vol. II; Bass)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712061807/http://photonics.intec.ugent.be/education/IVPV/res_handbook/v2ch33.pdf):

> *****Thermo-optic and Photoelastic Coefficients.***** Temperature is one of the main factors influencing the refractive index of solids. The thermo-optical coefficients $\partial ­n/\partial ­T$ (or $\partial \epsilon /\partial ­T$) can be estimated from a derivation of the Clausius-Mossotti relationship:
>
> $$
> \frac{1}{(\epsilon-1)(\epsilon+2)}\left({\partial\epsilon\over\partial T}\right) = -\alpha\left[1-{V\over\alpha_m}\left({\partial\alpha_m\over\partial V}\right)_T\right]+{1\over3\alpha_m}\left({\partial\alpha_m\over\partial T}\right)_v\tag{35}
> $$
> where $\alpha_m$ is the macroscopic polarizability. The first two terms are the principal contributors in ionic materials: a positive thermal expansion coefficient a results in a negative thermo-optic coefficient and a positive change in polarizability with volume results in a positive thermo-optic coefficient. In ionic materials with a low melting point, thermal expansion is high and the thermo-optic coefficient is negative (typical of alkali halides); when thermal expansion is small (indicated by high melting point, hardness, and high elastic moduli), the thermo-optic coefficient is positive, dominated by the volume change in polarizability (typical of the high-temperature oxides).
>
> Thermal expansion has no frequency dependence but polarizability does. At fre- quencies (wavelengths) near the edge of transparency, the polarizability (and $\partial\alpha_m /\partial ­V$) rises, and $\partial n/\partial ­T$ becomes more positive (or less negative). [...]
>
> A formalism similar to the preceding for the thermo-optic coefficient can be used to estimate the photoelastic constants of a material. The simplest photoelastic constant is that produced by uniform pressure, i.e., $dn/dP$. More complex photoelastic constants are tensors whose components define the effect of individual strain (elasto-optic coefficients) or stress (piezo-optic coefficients) tensor terms. Bendow et al., calculate $dn/dP$ and the elasto-optic coefficients for a number of cubic crystals and compare the results to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Light is an electromagnetic radiation having both electrical and magnetic fields . It’s motion through a matter has its interactions with it which depends on the matter through which it has to pass. The molecules themselves are moving with Brownian motion as in liquid or vibrating about its position , a property related to its energy state , which depends on temperature and molecular interactions with electromagnetic wave depends on electron clouds and it’s fields, it encounters while passing through it.
In case of gases, the void space increases with temperature or in layman’s language the density decreases so the hindrances to the passage of light decreases means refractive index of the medium decreases.
Let’s us have some optically active medium and you are able to control the concentration of optically active reagent in liquid, then not only light bends but it’s plain gets rotated depending on the optical reagent concentrations.
Here reason is electromagnetic interactions with optically active medium which not only slows down light but it bends too depending upon the intensity of such interaction on the path of plain polarised light. Here you observe bending ( change in refraction ) and Rotion of plain( due to optical interactions ) .